# App Engine: Launching a script upon update/run

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, less

I'm working with App Engine and I'm thinking about using the LESS CSS extension in my next project. There's no good LESS CSS library written in Python so  I went on with the original Ruby one which works great and out of the box. I'd like App Engine to execute `lessc ./templates/css/style.less` before running the development server and before uploading the files to the cloud. What is the best way to automate this? I'm thinking:

```
#run.sh:
lessc ./templates/css/style.less
.gae/dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite .
```

And

```
#deploy.sh
lessc ./templates/css/style.less
.gae/appcfg.py update .
```

Am I on the correct path or is there a more elegant way of doing things, perhaps at the appcfg.py level?

Thanks.

Comment: I really don't think there's an easier way. I use a similar way but for js with google closure compiler.

Comment: You could also look at http://sass-lang.com/ this will do it live while your developing. So you have a already compact css you can upload.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the javascript version of Less and hence do the less-to-css conversion in the browser.. simply upload your less formatted file (see http://lesscss.org/ for details).

Alternately, I do the conversion (first with less, now I use sass) in a deploy script which does a number of things

- checks that my source code control has no outstanding files checked out (uncommited changes)
- joins and minifies my .js code (and runs jslint over it) into a single file
- generates other content (including stamping the source code control version as a version number into certain key files and as a parameter on some files to avoid caching issues) so my main page pulls in scripts with URLs such as "allmysource.js?v=585".. the file might be static but the added params force cache invalidation
- calls appcfg to perform the upload *and checks the return code*
- makes some calls to the real site with wget to check the previously generated files are actually returned, by checking they're stamped with the expected version
- applies another source code control tag to say that the intended version was successfully deployed

My script also accepts a "-preview" flag in which case it doesn't actually do the upload, but reports the version control comments for what's changed since the previous deployment.

```
me@here $ ./deploy -preview
Deployment preview...
Would deploy v596 to the production site (currently v593, previously v587)
  594       Fix blah blah blah for X Y Z
  595       New feature nah nah nah 
  596       Update help pages
```

This is pretty handy as a reminder of what I need to put in things like a changelog

I plan to also expand it so that I can, as part of my source code control, add any code that needs running once only when deployed (eg database schema changes) and know that it'll be automatically run when I next deploy a new version.

Essence of the script below as people asked... it doesn't show my "check code, generate, join, and minify" as that's another script... I realise that the original question was asking about that step of course :) but you can see where you'd add the call to generate CSS etc

```
#!/bin/sh

function abort () {
    echo
    echo "ERROR: $1"
    echo "$2"
    exit 99
}

function warn () {
    echo
    echo "WARNING: $1"
    echo "$2"
}

# Overrides the Gentoo eselect mechanism to force the python version the GAE scripts expect
export EPYTHON=python2.5

# names of tags used to label bzr versions    
CURR_DTAG=deployed
PREV_DTAG=prevDeployed

# command line options
PREVIEW=0
IGNORE_BZR=0

# These next few vars are set to values to identify my site, insert your own values here...
APPID=your_gae_appid_here
ADMIN_EMAIL=your_admin_email_address_here
SRCDIR=directory_to_deploy
CHECK_URL=url_of_page_to_retrive_that_does_upload_initialisation

for ARG; do
    if [[ "$ARG" == "-preview" ]]; then
        echo "Deployment preview..."
        PREVIEW=1
    fi
    if [[ "$ARG" == "-force" ]]; then
        echo "Ignoring the fact some files may not be committed to bzr..."
        IGNORE_BZR=1
    fi
done
echo

# check bzr for uncommited changed    
BSTATUS=`bzr status`
if [[ "$BSTATUS" != "" ]]; then
    if [[ "$IGNORE_BZR" == "0" ]]; then 
        abort "There are uncommited changes - commit/revert/ignore all files before deploying" "$BSTATUS"
    else
        warn  "There are uncommited changes" "$BSTATUS"
    fi
fi

# get version of numbers of last deployed etc
currver=`bzr log -l1 --line                | sed -e 's/: .*//'`
lastver=`bzr log -rtag:${CURR_DTAG} --line | sed -e 's/: .*//'`
prevver=`bzr log -rtag:${PREV_DTAG} --line | sed -e 's/: .*//'`
lastlog=`bzr log -l 1 --line gae/changelog | sed -e 's/: .*//'`

RELEASE_NOTES=`bzr log --short --forward -r $lastver..$currver \
    | perl -ne '$ver = $1 if /^ {0,4}(\d+) /; print "  $ver $_" if ($ver and /^ {5,}\w/)' \
    | grep -v "^ *$lastver "`

LOG_NOTES=`bzr log --short --forward -r $lastlog..$currver \
    | perl -ne '$ver = $1 if /^ {0,4}(\d+) /; print "  $ver $_" if ($ver and /^ {5,}\w/)' \
    | grep -v "^ *$lastlog "`

# Crude but old habit - BUGBUGBUG is a marker in the code for things to be fixed before deployment
echo "Checking code for outstanding issues before deployment"
BUGSTATUS=`grep BUGBUGBUG js/*js`
if [[ "$BUGSTATUS" != "" ]]; then
    if [[ "$IGNORE_BZR" == "0" ]]; then 
        abort "There are outstanding BUGBUGBUGs - fix them before deploying" "$BUGSTATUS"
    else
        warn  "There are outstanding BUGBUGBUGs" "$BUGSTATUS"
    fi
fi

echo
echo "Deploy v$currver to the production site (currently v$lastver, previously v$prevver)"
echo "$RELEASE_NOTES"
echo

if [[ "$currver" -gt "$lastlog" && "$lastver" -ne "$lastlog" ]]; then
    echo "Changes since the changelog was last updated"
    echo "$LOG_NOTES"
    echo
fi

if [[ "$IGNORE_BZR" == "0" && $lastver -ge $currver ]]; then
    abort "There don't appear to be any changes to deploy..."
fi

if [[ "$PREVIEW" == "1" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

$EPYTHON -c "import ssl" \
    || abort "$EPYTHON can't find ssl module for $EPYTHON - download it from pypi and install with the inbuilt setup.py"

# REMOVED - call to my script that calls jslint, generates files and compresses JS etc
#   || abort "Generation of code failed"

/opt/google_appengine/appcfg.py --email=$ADMIN_EMAIL -v -A $APPID update $SRCDIR \
    || abort "Appcfg failed - upload presumably incomplete"

# move the tags to show we deployed properly
bzr tag -r $lastver --force ${PREV_DTAG}
bzr tag -r $currver --force ${CURR_DTAG}

echo
echo "Production site updated from v$lastver to v$currver (in turn from v$prevver)"
echo
echo "Now visiting $CHECK_URL to upload the source to the database"

# new version doesn't seem to always be there (may be caching by the webserver etc) to be uploaded into the database.. try again just in case
for cb in $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM ; do
    prodver=`wget $CHECK_URL?_cb=$cb -q -O - | perl -ne 'print $1 if /^\s*Rev #(\d+)\s*$/'`
    if [[ "$currver" == "$prodver" ]]; then
        echo "OK: New version $prodver successfully deployed"
        exit 0
    fi
    echo "Retrying the upload of source to the database"
    sleep 5
done
abort "The new source doesn't seem to be loading into the database" "Try 'wget $CHECK_URL?_cb=$RANDOM -q -O -'"
```

It's not particularly big or clever, but it automates the upload job

Comment: Tim, is your script available somewhere for inspiration?

Comment: Added the script into the answer above... hope it helps... shout if not :)